# Having git problem in React django project

Tags: reactjs, django, git, github

#### STATEMENT

I want to make project with django backend and React frontend. I have created a project using and then create a frontend react folder using `create-react-app`. Now I want to upload my **projectname** folder to my github repository. But when I add my files using `git add .` command from my root folder('projectname' folder). It shows some warnings given below. What should I do? Please help.

#### WARNING

```
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> frontend
hint: 
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached frontend
```

#### COMMAND THAT I HAVE USED

```py
$ virtualenv env 
$ source env/bin/activate 
$ pip install django
$ django-admin.py startproject projectname

$ cd django-react-demo

$ npm install -g create-react-app
$ create-react-app frontend
```

#### MY  FOLDER  STRUCTURE

```
projectname
│
└───frontend
│       ├──.node_modules
│       ├──public
│       ├──src
│       ├──gitignore
│       ├──README.md
│       ├──package.json
│       └──package_lock.json
│
│projectname
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing that error because you have a git repository nested inside another repository.

Your main project directory `projectname` has a `.git` directory, and the directory nested inside it `frontend` has another `.git` repo that `create-react-app` created. The git repo inside another repo is called a submodule. It's possible to work with submodules, but it has its own quirks.

The easiest way to get around your error is to use only one git repo in your main project directory and delete the `.git` directory inside `frontend` directory. Try the following steps:

Go into the `frontend` directory.

```
cd frontend
```

Delete the `.git` directory inside `frontend` directory.

```
rm -rf .git
```

Go back to your main project directory.

You should now be able to track all files inside the `frontend` directory inside your main directory.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your react project i.e. frontend is also a git repository. So, what you can do is, put the frontend on the outside of the projectname folder and use the API key that you have from the backend in the frontend for your work.
You can follow this link:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/build-a-to-do-application-using-django-and-react